# HTML use DatePicker and calculate age

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I am new to writing code and feel I'm making some minor novice styled mistakes. Guidance would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
    <summary>Age Calculator
</summary>

<p>This calculator will calculate the age of an individual, given their date of birth.</p>

<ul>
    <li>Enter the individual&#39;s <strong>Date of birth</strong> then click the <strong>Submit</strong> button.&nbsp;

        <ul>
            <li>Use the arrows or type the month, day and year.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Enter another individual&#39;s <strong>Date of birth</strong> then click the <strong>Submit</strong> button again to run the calculation again with a different value.</li>
</ul>
<script>
    function submitBirthday()
    {
        var minutes = 1000 * 60;
        var hours = minutes * 60;
        var days = hours * 24;
        var years = days * 365;
        var birthday = Date.parse(document.getElementById("thisBirthday").value);
        var dateNow = new Date();
        var YearsOld = Math.round((dateNow - birthday) / years);
        var YearsOld1 = Math.floor((dateNow - birthday) / years);
        var DaysOld = Math.floor((dateNow - birthday) / days);
        var days1 = Math.floor((DaysOld / 365.2425));
        var days2 = DaysOld / 365.2425;
        var days3 = parseFloat((days2 - days1)).toFixed(5);
        var days4 = Math.floor((days3 / 0.002738));


        document.getElementById("displayBirthday").innerHTML = ("This individual is " + days1 + " years and " + days4 + " days old.");
    }

</script>
<input type="date" id="thisBirthday" value="">
<button onclick="submitBirthday();">Submit</button>
<hr>
<div id="displayBirthday">
    <br>
</div>
```

e.g.
User picks 02/19/1980 and form returns
"This individual is 43 years old and 293 days old."

I've edited this post per Abra's (thanks Abra, took me a minute but I finally understood you) suggestions and updated it with how it's working today. I'd appreciate if someone with more experience has suggestion to be better and if there is a suggestion if I wanted to use two date pickers, if we need a measure of span between any two dates.

Thanks!

Comment: It's dropping my user input stuff and I can't seem to fix it. It just says my formatting is off. I don't know. the stuff with backslashes is the things I tried.

Comment: If your code is JavaScript, you should add the "javascript" tag to your question. Also, rather than post question details in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566292/html-use-datepicker-and-calculate-age#comment136744641_77566292), you should [edit] your question and add those details. Finally, you should consider taking the [tour].

Comment: As my comment stated I can not edit the post properly because it renders the code as not formatted in the attempt. I also can’t tag a JavaScript because it says I don’t have the necessary experience level to do so. I was hoping more of assistance with code. I’ve done it with a series of math equations, in the meantime, but wanted to learn a better method.

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)